# SwiftUI: How to select number of questions per player in Quiz?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and trying to build a quiz app. I've made it possible to add players and select which categories you want.. Now I'd like the user to have the option to select number of questions per user for a game session (10 questions/user for example). I'd try fiddling with it myself but not really sure where to start.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I understand that it was unclear what I'm asking help for. I need some help how to filter the questions based on how many questions the user selects. My idea is that the user, via a picker, can select 5, 10, 15 or 20 and that should reflect how many questions each user will get to answer in the quiz. And sorry if I'm not showing enough code, I'm just not sure what I should include.

Here's my simple view so far:

```
struct NumberSelectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GameVM

    enum Questions: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case five = 5
        case ten = 10
        case fifteen = 15
        case twenty = 20

        var id: Int { self.rawValue }
    }
    
    @State private var selectedOption = Questions.five
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("\(selectedOption.rawValue) questions")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("per player")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            }
            Picker("Select number of questions", selection: $selectedOption) {
                Text("\(5)").tag(Questions.five)
                Text("\(10)").tag(Questions.ten)
                Text("\(15)").tag(Questions.fifteen)
                Text("\(20)").tag(Questions.twenty)
            }
            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: GameView(),
                label: {
                    PrimaryButton(text: "Continue")
                }
            )
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Number of questions")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Here's a part of my ViewModel:

```
 // Filter questions based on active categories
    var filteredQuestions: [QuestionModel] {
        let filteredCategoryNames = categories
            .filter(\.isActive) // filters for the active categories
            .map(\.name) // turns it into an array containing the name of each category

        return questions.filter { question in
           filteredCategoryNames.contains(question.category)
        }
    }
    
    // Get question title for current question
    var questionTitle: String {
        game.currentQuestion.question
    }
    
    // Get category for current question
    var questionCategory: String {
        game.currentQuestion.category
    }
    
    // Get options for current question
    var optionIndices: Range<Int> {
        game.currentQuestion.options.indices
    }
    
    // Get text for each option for current question
    func optionText(for index: Int) -> String {
        game.currentQuestion.options[index]
    }
```

Here's a part of my GameView:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Spacer()
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                CategoryTagView(name: viewModel.questionCategory, iconSize: 20, textSize: 16)
                QuestionTitleView(text: viewModel.questionTitle, size: 32)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(viewModel.optionIndices) { index in
                    VStack(spacing: 16) {
                        OptionIconView(index: index)
                        Text(viewModel.optionText(for: index))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 120)
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(viewModel.colorForOption(at: index))
                    .cornerRadius(24)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.guessMadeForCurrentQuestion(at: index)
                        viewModel.calculateScore(at: index)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            viewModel.nextQuestion()
                        }
                    }
                    .disabled(viewModel.verifyGuess)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Without a [mre], this is likely very difficult if not impossible to give suggestions for.

Comment: What are you asking? There isn't a question here

Comment: " My idea is that the user, via a picker, can select 5, 10, 15 or 20 and that should reflect how many questions each user will get to answer in the quiz." -- I don't see a `Picker` in the code at all. Have you made an attempt to add one? "sorry if I'm not showing enough code, I'm just not sure what I should include." -- did you read the link I posted in the first comment? Ideally, you should include enough code that we can copy and paste it into Xcode to run it, with everything superfluous to the question removed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link, going to read up on that for potential future posts. I've updated with code for my SelectQuestionsView where I have my picker.